# How to access ELK services in browser?

Tags: elastic-stack

I am newbie to work in ELK. I am facing an issue here. I have a Ubuntu 16.04 VM and I have installed ELK services and all are running actively. To this VM, the domain is also configured to run on port 5601. But I am not able to access the kibana in my browser. Am I missing something here! Can you please help me?

Comment: What do you mean you can't access Kibana? Are you getting some type of error?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I was caught up with other work. I solved the issue. In kibana.yml file, the server.host was listening on "localhost" instead of 0.0.0.0.